# Javascript toggle button: change action sequence from show/hide to hide/show

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

I have the following script, that I found at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapsible),

```
<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

in order to make a toggle button for a text box. The problem is **the script initially shows the text box and then hides it**. I **want to first hide and then show**. Otherwise the **initial first click doesn't do anything, so users will think, the button is broken**.

To explain more, I use it with

```
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Toggle document map</button>
    <div class="content">
    <p>bla..bla</p>
    </div>
```

and following `css`.

```
  .active, .collapsible:hover {
    background-color: #8511ae;
    color: white; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;
}
  .collapsible {
    background-color: #faf9d8;
    color: #4e3fe3; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold;
    font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 35%;
    float: left
    border: 0px solid #8511ae;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 24%;
}
  .content {
    width: 35%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px solid #8511ae;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    background-color: #faf9d8;
}
```

The initial `content css` from w3schools, also includes

```
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
```

but since **I want the text box to initially being visible when visiting the page**,  I left the above 2 items, out of the `content` css.

But now, as aforementioned, I have to click the toggle button twice *(only the first time I do this)* to hide the text box.

**How can I modify the above `javascript` so that the first click hides instead of trying to make visible?**

I tried some changes on my own but I just broke the script. This is the first website I ever made, and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: dont use `.style` in JS in 2022. Using `.classList` is the mdoern approach. Also makes it easier to toggle stylse by simply using `.classList.toggle('class-name')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
if (content.style.display === "none") {
  content.style.display = "block";
} else {
  content.style.display = "none";
}
```

instead of:

```
if (content.style.display === "block") {
  content.style.display = "none";
} else {
  content.style.display = "block";
}
```

---

#### This is your code:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "none") {
      content.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.active, .collapsible:hover {
    background-color: #8511ae;
    color: white; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;
}
  .collapsible {
    background-color: #faf9d8;
    color: #4e3fe3; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold;
    font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 35%;
    float: left
    border: 0px solid #8511ae;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 24%;
}
  .content {
    width: 35%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px solid #8511ae;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    background-color: #faf9d8;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Toggle document map</button>
    <div class="content">
    <p>bla..bla</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The style read-only property returns the **inline style** of an
> element in the form of a CSSStyleDeclaration

[From `HTMLElement.style` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

Meaning when you use `content.style.display` (to either read or set its value) what you're acting on is the style that's written **[inline](https://www.codecademy.com/article/html-inline-styles)**.

Since `<div class="content">` doesn't have the inline style when the page first loads, your test `if (content.style.display === "block")` evaluates to `false`. It works the second time because your first click applied the block inline style with `content.style.display = "block"`.

One way to fix it is then to simply manually add the inline styling to your `content` element like so:

`<div class="content" style="display:block;">...`

so that your code can evaluate to `true` the first time you click the button.

Like other have said though, if you want to not use inline styles, you can use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) instead.